# Why does a line that used to compile now report an error (Property 'code' not found on object of type 'NSError *')?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The following chunk of code has been compiling successfully for some time now:

```
NSString *filePathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
_fileName = fileName;
filePathName = [filePathName stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSError *error;
_fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePathName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (error.code == 0)
```

A little while ago, Xcode started reporting the following error on the last line:

> Property 'code' not found on object of type 'NSError *'

Other files in the project have changed recently, but not this one.  Can someone please give me some help for how I can troubleshoot this situation?  TIA.

P.S. I pushed the project to GitHub, and a coworker pulled it.  It builds successfully on his machine.

Comment: Have you looked at your machine's copy of the header NSError.h?

Comment: BTW:  You should never test the error prior to testing the return value of the method that may or may not produce an error...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good only. Even though i have tried the same it build successfully on my machine. Just clean the build using `shift+cmd+K` and check.

Comment: Did try cleans, but they didn't help.  Actually solved it by discarding my local copy of the file and doing a pull from GitHub.  I'm guessing that my local copy of the file got corrupted somehow.